# TypeError at /home/register/ __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Tags: python, django, django-views

I m trying to register the user using a registration form.When I hit the register button the user gets registered but the redirection doesn't happen instead i m getting the error:

**TypeError at /home/register/ __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given**

**views.py**

```
class register(View):
form_class = UserForm
template_name = 'register.html'

def get(self, request): 
    form = self.form_class(None)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        auth_user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if auth_user is not None:

            if auth_user.is_active:
                login(request, auth_user)
                return  redirect('manager:home')

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

**register.html**

```
REGISTRATION
<form action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}
<button type="sbumit">REGISTER</button>
</form>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from .views import register,home, contact, contactList, login, logout

app_name = 'manager'

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', home.as_view(), name='home'),
url(r'^contact/$', contact, name='contact'),
url(r'^list/$', contactList, name='list'),
url(r'^register/$', register.as_view() , name='register'),
url(r'^login/$', login.as_view() , name='login'),
url(r'^logout/$', logout , name='logout'),

]
```

link to the whole code: [Github](https://github.com/rasikraj01/contact-manager)

[image: Error]

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `login` view is shadowing Django's login function. You need to rename that view to something else, say `LoginView`